# Default children route when typing parent URL

Tags: angular

Here is how my routes look like:

```
{
    path:'c/:competId',
    component: CompetitionComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path:'overview',
        component: CompetitionDescriptionComponent
      },
      {
        path:'leaderboard',
        component: CompetitionLeaderboardComponent
      },
      {
        path:'submit',
        component: CompetitionSubmitComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

Whenever the user type the `c/:competId` URL I want him to be redirected to the `overview` route by default

So I tried to implement it into the init function of the `CompetitionComponent`:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
   this.router.navigate(['c/' + params.competId + '/overview'])
});
```

But by doing this when I try to access to `leaderboard` by URL it redirects me to `overview` as well. I don't want this behavior.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have much eaiser ways to do that ... First solution, a redirect :

```
{
    path:'c/:competId',
    component: CompetitionComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path:'',
        redirectTo: 'overview',
        pathMatch: 'prefix'
      },
      {
        path:'overview',
        component: CompetitionDescriptionComponent
      },
      {
        path:'leaderboard',
        component: CompetitionLeaderboardComponent
      },
      {
        path:'submit',
        component: CompetitionSubmitComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

Second solution, a whole route with your component :

```
{
    path:'c/:competId',
    component: CompetitionComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path:'',
        component: CompetitionDescriptionComponent
      },
      {
        path:'overview',
        component: CompetitionDescriptionComponent
      },
      {
        path:'leaderboard',
        component: CompetitionLeaderboardComponent
      },
      {
        path:'submit',
        component: CompetitionSubmitComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I suppose the best practice solution would be the first one?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but I use the first one, so I'd say yes :D

Answer (score 0):

Change your route config to :

```
{
    path:'c/:competId',
    component: CompetitionComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path:'overview',
        component: CompetitionDescriptionComponent
      },
      {
        path:'leaderboard',
        component: CompetitionLeaderboardComponent
      },
      {
        path:'submit',
        component: CompetitionSubmitComponent
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: not `/overview`, `overview`. Using a slash will redirect to the root routing, not one of the children.

Comment: Yes you are right !! I will edit my answer. Thank you @trichetriche.